# IDEA переодически не видит классы

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Использую Manjaro Linux со всеми свежими пакетами и ядром. Недавно появилась проблема, которая затрагивает все проекты: в любой момент может "отвалиться" какой-то класс. Класс существует, отображается Intellj в подсказке, но будто отделён от проекта. Его не видят, он не видит

Пробовал:

1. Обновлять IDEA
2. Создавать чистый проект и переносить код
3. Устанавливать src как "root dir" через "mark as"
4. Переименовывать, менять пакет класса
5. Синхронизировать Maven
6. Удалять .idea, [project].iml и заново загружать проект

Пункты 2 и 4 и вправду работают, но лишь на время. Это не решение.

Если переименовывать и переносить через рефактор, в остальных частях проекта оно не меняется, приходится менять вручную. И после этого всё работает. Но это как-то... Ненормально.

Скрины для понимания:

[image: Пример 1]

[image: Пример 2]

[image: Пример 3]

Это не проблема кода. Код работал, класс публичный, метод публичный статический.

UPD: Забыл добавить, это касается и Maven зависимостей переодически. Они есть в Maven, но IDEA будто слепа. Добавление библиотеки через настройки проекта тоже не всегда помогало. 100% рабочее решение - добавлять локальные зависимости через Maven, но это ужасно.

Comment: file -> Invalidate Cashes -> Invalidate and restart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Помогло <kbd>File `->` Invalidate Cashes `->` Invalidate and restart</kbd>
Помог [@AlekseiGaile](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/326748/alekseigaile), спасибо.

Comment: не благодарите )))

Comment: Как минимум - стоило бы добавить авторство, например "по совету AlekseiGaile сделал вот так, помогло". А как максимум - написать в комментарии к своему вопросу "Алексей, помогло, опубликуйте ответом - я приму". Ну и, естественно, принять ответ :)

Comment: @kami Я обычно тут не сижу, на форумах нельзя отвечать благодарностью, максимум эмоцию оставить. Насчёт авторства - да, надо, добавлено

Answer (score 0):

На версии 2121.1 было так же. Знакомые тоже жаловались на баги. Откатился на 2020.3 и все прошло

Answer (score 0):

тоже помогло:

```
file -> Invalidate Cashes -> Invalidate and restart
```